# Null Reference from Passing Instance to Constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, null

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Agent : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private FSM brain;

    void Start ()
    {
        //Create the FSM that will control this agent
        brain = new FSM (this);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FSM
{
    //Agent this FSM is attached to
    private Agent agent;

    //Constructor
    public FSM (Agent FSMOwner)
    {
        agent = FSMOwner;
        Debug.Log (agent);
    }
}
```

So I have an empty game object which has the Agent script on it. When the program starts, the Agent script instantiates a new FSM class. In the FSM constructor it debugs the agent, but it keeps returning null.

So how do I pass the Agent class to the FSM class so they can communicate with eachother?

Comment: Something else is going on. Assuming you're calling `Start` on `Agent`, it looks fine as it is.

Comment: This doesn't reproduce. Show us how you're calling the object.

Comment: Start is called on the first frame of the game running. I believe it's a Unity function (this is for a game in Unity). 

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html

So Start is being called for definite, the constructor for FSM is getting called because I am seeing the debug message inside the constructor.

Comment: What keeps returning null? Is this the problematic code or this is the bit you _think_ is problematic? Try putting a breakpoint.